# Making Go compiler use int64 by default

Tags: go, numbers

Is there any way I can make the Go compiler use int64 by default on my system? I am writing code for project Euler on my 64 bit machine. There is little chance the code would be shared so there is no worry about running it on a 32 bit machine.

Comment: Why not just use `int64` instead of `int`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `int` type in go will be 64bits on 64bit machines in the next release, version 1.1. If you download the latest development code you can use it now.

There is no way to force `int` to be a certain size. However, when you use `int` you should never assume a particular size. Instead, explicitly type your numbers as int64.

Comment: Hi Stephen Weinberg, where can we get the Go's TODO list or next version info?